# Using elasticsearch with external database

Tags: database, elasticsearch, search, cassandra, full-text-search

Currently, I am working on elasticsearch but there is some basic problems.

So I created a cassandra database for storage and it already has too many fake records as sample data. I want to use elasticsearch as a search engine on this records for exercising with it but after some quick researches I saw that most of the people used elasticsearch as a database, but I just want to use it as a search engine.

In a nutshell, I want to create a structure that elasticsearch retrieves data from cassandra database. Is this possible to implement or just a futile efford?

I wish you all healthy and happy days!

Comment: Two older, related answers might help here.  One: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054954/elasticsearch-vs-cassandra-vs-elasticsearch-with-cassandra?rq=1

Comment: And the other: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61224168/elasticsearch-vs-elasticsearchcassandra?rq=1

Comment: Probably the best way to go about it is to send writes to a Pulsar or Kafka topic, and have the consumer persist in both Cassandra and Elastic.