# When i search for document after index a document. It returns empty but it returns document with sleep of 2 seconds between creating and fetching

Tags: python, elasticsearch, python-unittest, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am using Elasticsearch . I am trying to connect Elasticsearch with python.

I can create index with document. When i tried to fetch the same once successful creation done it returns empty.

If i make the code to sleep for 2 seconds after creating the data in Elasticsearch, then it returns actual data.

Is there any interval required to create and search the same data?

Sample code:

```
es_client.index(index=index_id, doc_type=doc_type, id=doc_id, body=body)

returns:
{'_index': 'account_001', '_type': 'UnitTest', '_id': '9f48ae128e4811e88c4b0242ac120013', '_version': 1, 'result': 'created', '_shards': {'total': 2, 'successful': 2, 'failed': 0}, 'created': True}

es_client.search(index=index_id, doc_type=doc_type, body=query, filter_path=filter_path)

returns {}
```

Comment: this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406674/elastic-search-get-doesnt-give-latest-document/42407323#42407323

Answer (score 0):

I got answer from elastic discuss forum

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/when-i-search-for-document-after-index-a-document-it-returns-empty-but-it-returns-document-with-sleep-of-2-seconds-between-creating-and-fetching/141480/3