# Elastic search returning empty result even when data is present

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have a scenario where elasticsearch (version 2.3) is not returning results even though data is present. 
The same request gets a response on retrying. But why does elastic search fails to fetch a response in the first time.

Any help in understanding

NOTE: I am querying the data using "match". So the text analyzer issue mustn't be in play (https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-beginner-troubleshooting). Also it gives result on retry

Found the answer for initial question: Updating the question

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-documents-read-and-write-work-in-elasticsearch-if-we-doing-this-on-the-same-document-simultaneously/125139

Comment: Found an answer for the first part of the question
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-documents-read-and-write-work-in-elasticsearch-if-we-doing-this-on-the-same-document-simultaneously/125139

After reading through the link, I think the search query should return the old document in the second case as well.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331154/how-long-does-it-take-from-getting-a-document-upserted-into-es-before-it-can-be/55331594?r=SearchResults&s=1|35.6137#55331594

Comment: Thanks for the response. The link gives the information on when to expect the updated document. The case happened with me is that I didn't get the document at all.

Comment: Can you add steps to replicate the problem with sample data.

Comment: problem is not replicable and happens very randomly once in 15 days types

Comment: We were not able to identify the root cause in 2.3 version. but issue is never reported till now after moving to ES6.8