# Elasticsearch[7.7]: Few updated document is not returned when query for it immediately but after 10-15 mins delay

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

In our application, we are updating more than one document at a time for a index_x. When queried for updated documents, it does not return updated data for few document, immediately. e.g. If I am updating 10 documents, 1 document update is not retrieved immediately but after 10 to 15 mins. It has been observed that, the missed data is updated after 10 or 15 mins. For index_x, we have set refresh parameter as default i.e. 1s

Below are the app configurations for app:

- JAVA: 11
- Spring Boot: 2.7.11
- Spring Data Elasticsearch: 4.2.12
- Elasticsearch client - 7.12.1
- Elasticsearch version on AWS - 7.7

I have gone through the documentations and post like [Elastic Search GET doesn't give latest document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406674/elastic-search-get-doesnt-give-latest-document), where it says we can use refresh parameter to get the correct result. In Application, we are using JAVA API to save and retrieve the documents. From 4.2 onwards, refresh option is not available for Elasticsearch repository, it is explicitly included when we perform update or save operations.

If the ES is explicitly refreshing the documents, why I am not getting the updated data when queried for the same. And why only for few documents?

UPDATED:
I observed that though I have sent the query to update document, it has not updated till next day also. I checked in Kibana as well. It returns old data.

Comment: Elasticsearch refresh document every 1s with `index.refresh_interval` parameter like you mentioned. You must see the updated value of documents after 1s. How many index are you sending the query to? Are all index refresh_intervals set to 1 second?
Are you using any `cache` mechanism inside of your application?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have checked for refresh_interval parameter and it is set as 1s. Also, I am updating only one index at a time. I have checked in application also, no cache is used. Any idea why only for few documents it takes time to show updates data?

Comment: You're welcome. `not retrieved immediately but after 10 to 15 mins` this sentence directly refer to `refresh_interval` parameter. If you are using `_update_by_query` API call can you try with `?refresh` parameter? 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#_refreshing_shards_2

Comment: I am not using rest API, but I am using JAVA API with below code:                                   ElasticsearchRepository.saveAll(document).  Not sure how I can use "refresh" parameter.

Comment: check this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-update-by-query.html#_optional_arguments_8

`request.setRefresh(true);`

Comment: How much stress does your cluster have generally? Is it write-intensive? How do you "query" for the document? By Search or by Get? Is your application maybe sending multiple similar updates, but the oldest one wins (can you track what update is visible in the index)? Do you have some logs in elsticsearch about replication problems (does your index have replica shards)?

Comment: @davisca- We are using search query not get. And yes it is write-intensive? App is not sending multiple updates.  Index setting are: "number_of_shards" : "1" and "number_of_replicas" : "1"

Comment: @MusabDogan - In our application, we are using elastisearch search repository to save the document. we are not using UpdateByQueryRequest.